# FxCop analyzers do not show warnings on the fly

Tags: c#, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using the FxCop Analyzers NuGet package (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers) to get analysis results in the error list while typing.

The issue is that the FxCop analyzers are not returning CA1707 errors (underscore) while typing (or after loading the solution) while I get the CA1707 when I select 'Enable Code Analysis on build' in the project build settings or manual run the static code analysis.

Note that this is not specific to 1707, also CA1008 only pops up during static code analysis run. So it looks like an issue of the FxCop analyzer itself...

What can be the issue here ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only does the analysis on a build and not "on the fly".

Comment: Analyzers are always 'Live' (as you type), a build shouldn't be neccessary... and after a rebuild solution still no warnings (where I expect warnings because I have unit tests with public method names which include underscores)

Comment: I'm just saying that I don't remember ever having Code Analysis errors while typing, only when doing a build or when I specifically ran Code Analysis, but I have not used it in VS 2015, so maybe they changed it, but I doubt it because I believe the analysis is done of the compiled code.

Comment: The Analyzers package is a re-implementation of the build-time analyzer. And yes, it does edit-time checking. However, not all checks are implemented yet. At least, that is my understanding, I don't have a link for that.

Comment: @Hans: you could be right here.... thx

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 or later, you need to [enable full solution analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt709421.aspx).

It's in Options > Text Editor > C#/Basic > Advanced.